# react-router-dom get id from route with custom components and extra path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an app that uses a react-router-config and uses a [wrapper component](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-route-that-redirects.html) to redirect unauthenticated users.

I have some functionality that requires the use of the route /tasks/:id but I am unable to access the :id value to perform the necessary task lookup.

My routes.js:

```
import React from "react";
...
const Tasks = React.lazy(() => import("./Components/Tasks"));
...
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/tasks/edit/:id",
    name: "View Task",
    component: Tasks
  }
...
];
export default routes;
```

Then I have `AuthenticatedRoute.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AuthenticatedRoute({
  component: C,
  appProps,
  ...rest
}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        appProps.isAuthenticated ? (
          <C {...props} {...appProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={`/login?redirect=${props.location.pathname}${props.location.search}`}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

and in the App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthenticatedRoute from "./components/AuthenticatedRoute/AuthenticatedRoute";
import routes from "./routes";

function App(props) {
...
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
        <Switch>
            {routes.map((route, idx) => {
              return route.component ? (
                <AuthenticatedRoute
                  key={idx}
                  path={route.path}
                  exact={route.exact}
                  name={route.name}
                  appProps={props}
                  component={props => <route.component {...props} />}
                />
              ) : null;
            })}
        </Switch>
...
      </React.Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Finally I have my Tasks.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
...
function Tasks(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  const onLoad = async () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(props.match.params));
  };
...
```

Browsing to localhost:3000/tasks/1. `props.match.params` is empty in every component up the chain. `props.match.params.id` is `undefined`. I have also tried match with `{match.params.id}` but that is also undefined at every component.

I can see `props.location.pathname` but that is the full path and I would have to manually get the last segment. I can't get it to automatically grab the `:id` from the url.

**EDIT**
Turns out my example was too simplified, which actually helped me identify the issue. In my previous version when I had the route:

```
  {
    path: "/tasks/:id",
    name: "View Task",
    component: Tasks
  }
```

everything actually works fine using `useParams` I am able to get the `:id` value. What I actually have in my app and what seems to be breaking it is adding an additional directory to the path:

```
  {
    path: "/tasks/edit/:id",
    name: "View Task",
    component: Tasks
  }
```

I am not sure how this makes a difference, but having the extra `/edit` seems to break the `useParams`

Comment: Try using `const { id } = useParams();`. Import useParams accordingly from react-router-dom.

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox or something?

Comment: When creating the codesandbox I think I found what the issue is. my route has an extra path which seems to be breaking it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`react-router-dom` provides some handy hooks. In your case, I'd suggest [`useParams()`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) (link to docs)

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent {
  let { id } = useParams();

  return (<p>{id}</p>);
}
```

I'd also probably opt for not using `withRouter` if you will be using the hooks provided by React Router

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. I created a new page in my app with only a single base path `/test/:id` and your code worked. When I added the extra directory (which is what my app actually has) `/test/edit/:id` It no longer works.

Comment: [Check out this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-yalow-ydl9x): `let { id } = useParams()` _should_ work

Comment: my path is /student/general/request/:id. i can get the id but i need to check whether it's general or not. any way to capture that general part of path ?

Comment: @Ravisara You can use [`useLocation()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

Comment: Thanks. with my code it can be done with " let { id, type } = useParams()"

Comment: That will work if your path is like `/student/:type/request/:id`

Comment: This is the updated link to the docs [link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params)

Answer (score 2):

Martins answer is correct and works for functional components.
I had the same problem, however I was using a class component (class Company extends Component) and Martins answer did not work for that case.
If you have a class component you can do:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // here you have the id
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
      }

}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```